# View and SurfaceView, which one is better?

Tags: android

What is the difference between View and SurfaceView? Which one should be used for getting better and fast results?
Why SurfaceHolder is used in SurfaceView?

Comment: View is parent for [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and every other *View class.

Comment: WHat is it you are trying to do? "Better and faster results" - meaning what?

Comment: yes thats what i am trying

Comment: We know you're trying, but what does better and faster mean?  Better what? What does "better" mean?  What does "faster" mean? Faster coding?  Faster compilation?  Faster rendering of text? Faster drawing bitmaps?

Comment: I mean better and faster drawing,speed and redrawing(next frames).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SurfaceView behaves just like a View.

If you need to draw a static component (such TextViews) you should use a View.

A SurfaceView must be used if you need to draw your view several times (such in a video player, a game, animation and so on), with the SurfaceHolder you can draw your view in a off-screen Canvas and post it to be drawn in the SurfaceView (also called Double-Buffering) it's usefull if you want to draw in a Thread.