# Android: Drawing on Continuous ScrollView

Tags: android

My requirement is similar (not the same, of course) to the [GuitarTuna](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ovelin.guitartuna&hl=en) app. I want to draw on an infinite vertical `ScrollView` as follows:

[image]

A trail emanating from the bottom of the pin on the top of the screen can be seen in the image above. It keeps scrolling with the `ScrollView` and disappears (by scrolling out of the screen) if the drawing is stopped.

What is the best way to create a similar kind of drawing interface?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, Its very unclear.

Comment: I just checked the app, You mean the top part that scrolls when the marker is moving?

Comment: @krishan: That's precisely what I was indicating at.

Comment: Guitartuna doesn't use a scrollview, the whole app view is a surface view, they draw the scroll effect directly on the canvas.

Comment: I understand, can you please provide an example on how to get the scrolling effect on the SurfaceView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Hi!

Finally, i think, i understand what you need.
I really don't know if is possible to achieve by this using the example that you mention.

I would try the option of using a `SurfaceView.`
Here's what i have until now:

An interesting answer about how to draw inside scrollView:

[How to draw on canvas greater than screen size and be able to scroll / pan horizontally and vertically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397829/how-to-draw-on-canvas-greater-than-screen-size-and-be-able-to-scroll-pan-horiz)

How to draw in a SurfaceView:
[example 1](http://android-er.blogspot.com.ar/2014/03/simple-surfaceview-example.html)
[example 2](http://android-coding.blogspot.com.ar/2011/05/basic-implementation-of-surfaceview.html)

Complete example of draw using `TouchListener` in a `SurfaceView`

[How to draw to Canvas from SurfaceView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266994/how-to-draw-to-canvas-from-surfaceview)

Good answers that explains how a SurfaceView works :

[Android: How to draw on a Surfaceview which already is displaying a Camara Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876328/android-how-to-draw-on-a-surfaceview-which-already-is-displaying-a-camara-previ?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[View and SurfaceView, which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113755/view-and-surfaceview-which-one-is-better?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Ideas on how to scroll a surfaceView?

[Android SurfaceView scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096618/android-surfaceview-scrolling)

I wish to have more time to help you, and change my answer with some code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I truly appreciate the effort. But, my use case is a bit different. What I want to make here is a live plotter like application. I want to draw real time data. There are libraries for that but the disadvantage with them is that they plot the data before scrolling. Whereas in my case, I literally want to draw. Imagine a canvas that is scrolling vertically in front of you and you have a pen that you can move only horizontally. I suggest that you try using GuitarTuna once to get the exact idea.

Comment: I saw the effect in the app, i think that @wrkwrk 's comment is the correct way. I'll try to edit my answer with something that really helps you. Can you provide examples of the libraries that you mention?

Comment: Sure, there's this library that does it: http://www.android-graphview.org/realtime-chart/

Comment: Well, with the limited time I had, I finally succeeded in implementing what I wanted using a NestedScrollView, and drawing on the canvas of a custom View which is inside the NestedScrollView. I will post the code in a day or two.

Comment: For those who might question why I have accepted this answer: I am accepting this answer for the sincere effort, the spirit of helping someone out, and the direction that it provided me on the basis of which I was able to get my work done.